# Is there a way for Moodle Single-Sign-On from a Laravel Application?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, moodle, laravel-5.7

I'm setting up a single-sign-on feature for moodle from a laravel website.

1. User accesses the laravel site
2. User logs in
3. User clicks a link to Moodle
4. The user is automatically logged into Moodle without having to reenter their username and password.

If the user bookmarks or directly accesses Moodle, they can still login directly there with their username and password.

I have tried to user php cURL to post username and password to the login url.

```
$url =  "http://moodle.site.com.na/sso/login/index.php";
$postData = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
try {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    dd($e);
}
return $response;​
```

When the single-sign-on is successful, then the user should be automatically logged into moodle site without having to re-enter their username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - there are a couple common solutions depending on your needs:

- Use/customize an existing SSO authentication plugin - this is great if you have already implemented a certain type of authentication in your app - e.g. SAML, OAuth, OpenID, etc.:
  https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=21
- Create your own authentication plugin: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins

Hope it goes well!

Comment: I need help on how to do it, below is my scenario...

User accesses the main siteA
User logs in siteA
User clicks a link to Moodle(SiteB)
The user is automatically logged into Moodle(SiteB) without having to reenter their info
If the user bookmarks or directly accesses Moodle(SiteB), they can still login directly there